# Use function in replace for preg_replace()

Tags: php

I need to use a function in `preg_replace()` like this:

```
$out = preg_replace($regex, "[ ".$this->ToMobileFormatt("$0")." ]", $input);
```

but it doesn't work true.

The fuction and regex .

`$regex = '~((?:\+?989|09)|(?:\+?98 9|09)|(?:\+?9|09))(\s|-)*\d{1}(\s|-)*\d{1}(\s|-)*\d{1}(\s|-)*\d{1}(\s|-)*\d{1}(\s|-)*\d{1}(\s|-)*\d{1}(\s|-)*\d{1}(\s|-)*\d{1}~';`

```
function ToMobileFormatt($string)
{


    $string = str_replace(" ","",$string);
    $string = str_replace(" ","",$string);


    if ( preg_match('/^\0\d{10}/', $string) AND count($string) == '11' ) 
    {
        return $string ;
    } 
    elseif( preg_match('/^\98\d{10}/', $string) )
    {
        $string = substr($string,2);
        $string = '0'.$string ;
        return $string ;
    }

    return $string;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: you'll need to add more info to get a proper answer, what are the values of all the variables?

Comment: that is Phone number

Comment: As mike said, what are the actual values of regex and input? What does it do? As off now it's hard to answer

Comment: I edit question please read it again thanks .@SketchyCoder . @mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/it/function.preg-replace-callback.php) ;)
something like this (may vary depending on your regex):

```
$out = preg_replace_callback($regex, 'ToMobileFormatt', $input);

function ToMobileFormatt($matches)
{

    $string = str_replace(" ","",$matches[0]);
    $string = str_replace(" ","",$string);


    if ( preg_match('/^\0\d{10}/', $string) AND count($string) == '11' ) 
    {
        return $string ;
    } 
    elseif( preg_match('/^\98\d{10}/', $string) )
    {
        $string = substr($string,2);
        $string = '0'.$string ;
        return $string ;
    }

    return "[ ".$string."]";
}
```

Comment: Thanks . How i should use `$this->ToMobileFormatt($0)` in preg_replace_callback ?

Comment: `$out = preg_replace_callback($regex, [$this,'ToMobileFormatt'], $input);`. Otherwise you can set ToMobileFormatt as static method and call it as `YourClass::ToMobileFormatt`, which is a little bit more readable in my opinion :)